# Why do my Junit tests fail when running them all one time?

Tags: java, junit

I have a bunch of Junit tests. When I run them individually by right clicking each class and then "run as" -> "Junit test", they all passed. However, if I click a package or click src/test/java to run all at the same time, many of them fails and some passed.

Is this normal?

Comment: Maybe your tests depends on other tests' results. If it is the case, you should change that because unit tests should be independent from each other.

Comment: Or if you're using member variables, one test could change the member variable that another test is expecting to be in a certain state.  You can use '@Before' and '@After' to set variables before and after each test.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend other tests. The reason for failure seems to be the different output order of string values in a hashset that are asserted. They are actually the same. However, I don't understand why when individually running without problems. All passed.

Comment: @blur0224, All tests work as getting a value (variable) returned by a function. Is this the member variables you are talking about?

Comment: Many also failed when running them at command line with "mvn clean install"

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code or a complete reproducible example.  You have to be careful with the state of objects shared between tests.  I would run the test on debug and compare what that method returns when running a single test vs all the tests.

Comment: No shared variable in my unit test class, all testXYZ() methods are defining their own variables. I suspect it is due to the random order of HashSet values in the assertion, but I don't understand why they all passed when running individually.

Comment: It's only normal if your code or your tests are buggy...

Comment: Also static variables are shared between tests. And, since HashSets have no order, your asserts must not depend on order.

Comment: If your tests depend on the output order of a hash table, then that's your bug.  The sequence of Strings produced by iterating a HashSet, for example, should be regarded as non-deterministic.  Check for counts, check for existence of particular values, but don't check for whether values are iterated in some consistent fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience this indicates that tests are not properly cleaning themselves up.  If you have any tests that invoke static methods, for example, those static calls may change the state of static objects in ways that will influence future tests.  For static members, only one instance exists, so when the tests run they will all use the same instance.  So when running individually, they may work fine because they make use of a static object in its pristine state, but when running as part of a suite some other test may have interacted with the static object in ways that cause code to run differently for subsequent tests.

So in such a case you could add an @After or @AfterClass method that will reset anything that may have been changed when running your tests.

Comment: If that's really the case, does that mean the use of the static variable in my code has a problem?

Comment: Not necessarily, but potentially.  It may just mean that a test needs to clean up so it doesn't pollute a future test.  Or it could indicate that code will interact with a static variable in ways that cause problems with other code that also interacts with the same static member.  Really without seeing all the tests and all the code it is virtually impossible to say with any certainty.  But I recommend you find all cases where a unit test may invoke a static method and consider if these will cause changes that would pollute the state for future tests.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.